# Unique click listener for each new added button with javascript

Tags: javascript, button, dynamic, click, listener

I'm adding dynamic buttons on a certain event in this way:

```
...

var count = 0;

var html button = '<button type="button" class="add-condition @(Model.Name) ' + count + ' btn btn-default" name="add-condition @(Model.Name)">Add</button><div class="conditions @(Model.Name) ' + count + '">'

count++;

...
```

and the event click listener is:

```
@*$(".add-condition." +  modelActivityElements.Name, $(this)).click(function (e) {

 });
```

I'd like to handle the click for **N** buttons added dynamically, but in this way the click is triggered **N** times.

How to handle a single click ?

Comment: are you calling the same function for every click?

Comment: yes, but I've to pass different parameters (different name of the clicked button) to handle different situations

Comment: Put the parameters in `data-whatever` attributes in the button and then handle all the buttons with 1 function that uses `$(this).data("whatever")` values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are initializing the click handlers inside the loop. Rather initialize listeners outside the loop, and get the button specific parameters inside the event handler.

```
$('.add-caption').click(function() {
   var name = $(this).attr('name') // @Model.name
   // do other stuff
});
```

Comment: If I initialize the click handler outside the loop, only the first button react on click handlers...

Comment: please update your question with the rendered html and what selector are you using?

Answer (score -2):

Are you adding dynamic buttons on a loop

Comment: Don't post comments as answers, even if you can't comment.  Build rep in order to comment, rather than circumvent the rules and mess up the site.